# Problema kable rmarkdown última línea pdf

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

tengo un problema con una tabla larga al hacer knit con rmarkdown. No sé por qué me repite la última línea de la tabla, pero fuera de la tabla y sin formato (como se ve en la imagen):

[image: tabla]

Sabéis cómo podría solucionarlo?.

Me he dado cuenta de que si cambio en el código de kable la opción booktabs = TRUE por FALSE, entonces ya no aparece la repetición de la última línea de la tabla. ¿Creeís que podría venir el error por ahí?

Os adjunto parte del código.
Así es como empieza el documento:

````
```
---
title: Colegios
author: David Sánchez
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d/%m/%Y')`"
documentclass: article
principal: true
forprint: false 
fontsize: 12pt 
toc: true
lang: es

geometry: margin = 2.5cm 
titlepage: true
titlepage-rule-color: "377DA6"
titlepage-background: "/Portada.pdf"
urlcolor: blue

output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: no
    number_sections: yes
   #toc: yes
    fig_caption: yes
    template: eisvogel

header-includes:
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm}
  \addtolength{\footskip}{-1.25cm}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
  \usepackage{pdflscape}
  \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
  \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}


---
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\textit{\leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
````

Y así es como está redactado el código en la parte de la tabla. Es una tabla muy grande, por lo que he tenido que rotar la disposición de la hoja y quitarle el pagestyle.

````
 \newpage
 \blandscape
 \pagestyle{empty}
    
    ## Anexo 2. Inventario
    
    ```{r table_Anexo2}
    options(knitr.kable.NA = '')
    
    
    dataInventario %>%
    kable(caption = "Inventario de luminarias",
          align=rep('c', 13),
          booktabs = TRUE,
          longtable=TRUE
    ) %>%
    kable_styling(
      latex_options =  c("striped","repeat_header","scale_down"), 
      position = "center",
      full_width = FALSE,
      font_size = 5,
      repeat_header_text = "(Continuaci\\'on)",
      repeat_header_continued="(Contin\\'ua en la siguiente p\\'agina)")%>%
      row_spec(0, bold=TRUE)
    
    
    ```
    
    \elandscape
    
    \newpage
    ## Anexo 3.
````

Ok, el archivo .tex justo en el apartado de la tabla pone lo siguiente:

```tex
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{empty}

\hypertarget{anexo-2.-inventario}{%
\subsection{Anexo 2. Inventario}\label{anexo-2.-inventario}}

\begingroup\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont

\begin{longtable}[t]{ccccccccc}
\caption{\label{tab:table_Anexo2}Inventario de luminarias}\\
\toprule
\cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Zona}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Ubicación}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Localización}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Nombre}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Tipo de Luminaria}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Número de Luminarias}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Número de lámparas}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Potencia de Lámpara (W)}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Potencia Instalada (W)}}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Inventario de luminarias (Continuaci\'on)}\\
\toprule
\cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Zona}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Ubicación}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Localización}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Nombre}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Tipo de Luminaria}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Número de Luminarias}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Número de lámparas}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Potencia de Lámpara (W)}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{86C0C4}{\textbf{Potencia Instalada (W)}}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{9}{r@{}}{(Contin\'ua en la siguiente p\'agina)}\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\cellcolor{gray!6}{EDIFICIO} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{P. BAJA} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{INTERIOR} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{ACCESO ASEO I PATIO} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{TUBO T8 FLUORESCENTE} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{1} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{2} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{36} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{72}\\
EDIFICIO & P. BAJA & INTERIOR & ACCESO ASEO II PATIO & TUBO T8 FLUORESCENTE & 1 & 2 & 36 & 72\\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{EDIFICIO} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{P. BAJA} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{INTERIOR} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{ASEO COCINA} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{PANTALLA ESTANCA T8 INCANDESCENTE} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{1} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{1} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{36} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{36}\\
EDIFICIO & P. BAJA & INTERIOR & ASEO I PATIO & TUBO T8 FLUORESCENTE & 2 & 2 & 36 & 144\\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{EDIFICIO} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{P. BAJA} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{INTERIOR} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{ASEO I PATIO} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{EMERGENCIA} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{1} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{1} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{}\\
\addlinespace

.... por aquí va toda la parrafada de la tabla...

PABELLÓN GIMNASIO & P. BAJA & INTERIOR & SALA BALLET & EMERGENCIA & 1 & 1 &  & \\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{PABELLÓN GIMNASIO} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{P. BAJA} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{INTERIOR} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{VESTUARIOS I} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{PANTALLA ESTANCA T8 FLUORESCENTE} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{4} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{2} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{36} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{288}\\
PABELLÓN GIMNASIO & P. BAJA & INTERIOR & VESTUARIOS I & EMERGENCIA & 1 & 1 &  & \\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{PABELLÓN GIMNASIO} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{P. BAJA} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{INTERIOR} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{VESTUARIOS II} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{PANTALLA ESTANCA T8 FLUORESCENTE} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{4} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{2} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{36} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{288}\\
\addlinespace
PABELLÓN GIMNASIO & P. BAJA & INTERIOR & VESTUARIOS II & EMERGENCIA & 1 & 1 &  & \\*
\end{longtable}

IO \& P. BAJA \& INTERIOR \& VESTUARIOS II \& EMERGENCIA \& 1 \& 1 \& \&
\textbackslash* \textbackslash end\{longtable\} \endgroup{}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Actualización:

He añadido una fila más al data frame. Debo decir que el data frame es una tabla normal de datos, sin nada raro ni símbolos ni nada parecido. El caso es que he añadido una nueva línea al final de la tabla y esto es lo que ha sucedido. Adjunto una imagen y la parte final del archivo .tex:

[image: Tabla]

```
PABELLÓN GIMNASIO & P. BAJA & INTERIOR & VESTUARIOS I & EMERGENCIA & 1 & 1 &  & \\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{PABELLÓN GIMNASIO} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{P. BAJA} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{INTERIOR} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{VESTUARIOS II} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{PANTALLA ESTANCA T8 FLUORESCENTE} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{4} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{2} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{36} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{288}\\
\addlinespace
PABELLÓN GIMNASIO & P. BAJA & INTERIOR & VESTUARIOS II & EMERGENCIA & 1 & 1 &  & \\
\cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{} & \cellcolor{gray!6}{}\\*
\end{longtable}

!6\}\{\} \& \cellcolor{gray!6}{} \& \cellcolor{gray!6}{} \&
\cellcolor{gray!6}{} \& \cellcolor{gray!6}{} \& \cellcolor{gray!6}{} \&
\cellcolor{gray!6}{} \& \cellcolor{gray!6}{} \&
\cellcolor{gray!6}{}\textbackslash* \textbackslash end\{longtable\}
\endgroup{}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Es basnate extraño porque en otras tablas que tengo en el documento no hace nada parecido.

CULPABLE:

Acabo de encontrar al culpable. Se trata de la orden repeat_header_continued de Kable_Styling. Al eliminarla desaparece el problema. También desaparece el texto que me indica que "Continúa en la siguiente página", pero eso es un mal menor.

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso al latex intermedio que generaría tu código? Si es así, pega en la pregunta el texto correspondiente a la tabla generada (puedes omitir la mayor parte de las filas, si quieres, pero deja las cabeceras iniciales y las últimas filas, así como los comandos finales de cierre)

Comment: Cambia `keep_tex` a `yes` y eso dejara en el disco el fichero intermedio tex al que yo me refería en el comentario anterior. Es importante ver la parte de ese documento que corresponde a la tabla, pues el error está en ese fichero intermedio (aunque posiblemente causado por el código r)

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia, ahora creo que he entendido a lo que te referías.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo siento, esto no es una respuesta sino más bien un comentario, pero por razones de espacio tengo que redactarlo en la zona de respuestas, pues en un comentario no me cabe.

### El problema

El problema es que, como se ve en el código LaTeX intermedio que knitr ha generado, la tabla es finalizada correctamente, pero luego añade parte del texto de la última línea, procesado de forma especial:

```tex
\begin{longtable}[t]{ccccccccc}
% ... muchas cosas aqui ...
% La siguiente tendría que ser la última fila de la tabla
PABELLÓN GIMNASIO & P. BAJA & INTERIOR & VESTUARIOS II & EMERGENCIA & 1 & 1 &  & \\*
\end{longtable}

% Y ahora se repite, pero con un código LaTeX diferente, que luego explicaré
IO \& P. BAJA \& INTERIOR \& VESTUARIOS II \& EMERGENCIA \& 1 \& 1 \& \&
\textbackslash* \textbackslash end\{longtable\} \endgroup{}
```

### El culpable?

Lo que es muy curioso es que esa línea que aparece fuera de la tabla, en realidad ha sido procesada por algún tipo de scripts, pues si te fijas, en lugar de utilizar `&` para separar los contenidos de las celdas (como ocurre con la penúltima línea), usa en cambio `\&` con un `\` delante. No solo eso, sino que enlugar de terminar por `\\*` como otras filas, termina con la secuencia `\textbackslash* \textbackslash`

Este procesamiento sirve para que cuando LaTeX procese esa parte no dé errores. El comando `\&` sirve para que en el PDF aparezca un `&`, gracias a la barra delante. Sin esa barra sería un error de compilación por aparecer el `&` fuera de la tabla. Análogamente el comando `\textbackslash` sirve para que en el PDF salga un `\` (carácter que no se puede usar "sin más" en LaTeX porque es el prefijo de los comandos).

En resumen, "alguien" ha decidido que esa última línea *no debería salir en la tabla* y se ha tomado las molestias de procesarla para que salga "bien" en el PDF fuera de la tabla.

### La causa?

Por desgracia desconozco la causa, y por eso esto no es una respuesta. No tengo a mi alcance un entorno R ni knitr, ni tengo tus datos para poder replicar el problema y poder indagar más. Tampoco sé nada de R (aunque sí de LaTeX).

Es posible que la última fila ya esté mal de alguna forma en los datos de entrada? ¿Quizás alguna cadena dentro de la tabla contiene un `\` o carácter especial que "confunde" al script que debe convertirlo en LaTeX? Un indicio de que por aquí podrían venir los tiros es que esa línea comienza por "IO", que son las últimas letras de GIMNASIO. De alguna forma se ha comido parte del texto.

¿O será que la última línea del dataframe es tratada de forma diferente por la razón que sea?

¿Puedes probar a añadir al dataframe una línea más y ver qué pasa? ¿Sigue saliendo mal la línea que daba problemas (y la que va después), o ahora la línea que daba problemas ya sale dentro de la tabla, pero la que sale fuera es la nueva última? Si ocurre esto segundo, una solución chapucera podría ser añadir una última línea vacía al dataframe, si ésto fuera posible...